# Exporting single band GeoTIFF in RGB from a multi band GeoTIFF

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff

I am processing 2-band images in R. As part of the processing, I need to export a single band RGB composite that maintains the spatial information of the original GeoTIFF. I have searched and searched and can only find how to plotRGB() and how to writeRaster(). PlotRGB loses the spatial information and writeRaster() produces a multi-band image.
What I need is a single band GeoTIFF with a combination of my 2 band.

Any ideas? There is a built in raster in R that can be used.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
x <- RGB(r)
plotRGB(x)  #Is there a way to output this where it will maintain spatial information?
writeRaster(x, filename="file.tif")  #This produces a 3-band tiff, not a composite
```

Comment: How do you want to combine your two bands into one band? Or do you mean you want to put your two bands into R and G and leave B of an RGB **3 band** image empty?

Answer (score 0):

I want to combine theme.
I want this result (see 1st image) in a single band (it's a Geotiff with 2 band, dysplayed as an RGB with R=bande1 G=bande2 B=bande2
[image]

I already combine theme with satck but its not the same result
[image]

```
#first image (what i need in a single band)
 
Joha = brick('Cnv.tif')
plotRGB(Joha, r=1, g=2, B=2) 

  
#combined with stack but not the result I want

joha_stack <- stack('Cnv.tif')
names(joha_stack) <- c('a', 'b')
rgb <- (joha_stack[['a']] - joha_stack[['b']])
plot(rgb, col = rev(terrain.colors(4)), main = 'RGB',stretch='hist')


mycolor <- c("#0000ff","#ff0000")
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(rgb, col = rev(terrain.colors(3)), main = 'RGB')
plot(knr, main = 'Unsupervised classification RGB')
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your original post with the additionnal details, instead of posting it as an answer.